# Realtime data from a service in ionic / angular

Tags: angular, ionic-framework, service, chart.js

Currently, I've got an application setup with a service which correctly gets realtime data from where I need it. I can access these values in realtime fine through the html, but I'm trying to implement a Chart.js chart in the page, which currently resides in `ngOnInit()`, meaning it's created once and then not updated. How would I go about setting up some kind of method that can watch the values in the service in real-time, so that I can consequently call an update for the graph?

For reference:

**tab1.page.ts**

```
export class Tab1Page {
  @ViewChild("barCanvas", { static: true }) barCanvas: ElementRef;
  private barChart: Chart;
...
ngOnInit() {
    this.barChart = new Chart(this.barCanvas.nativeElement, {
...
```

**tab1.page.html**

```html
<ion-card-content>
      <canvas #barCanvas></canvas>
</ion-card-content>
```

The data on the initial creation is pulled from some public fields:

**mqtt.service.ts**

```
export class MqttService {
  public livingCount: number = 0;
...
```

Comment: You can use a subject in the service, and subscribe to its value in the tab1.page

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use Observable or Subject to listen data stream in realtime.
Your your socket service probably will be like below.

```
export class MqttService {
private mqttClient:any;//any mqtt implementation library
  connect(params:any): {
    this.mqttClient = mqtt.connect('connection url');
  }
  onTopic(topic: string,header:any): Observable<any> {
  //subscribe any topic here.
    return Observable.create((observer) => {
          this.mqttClient.observe(topic).subscribe((message) => {
              observer.next(JSON.parse(message.payload.toString()));
            },header);
    });
  }
}
```

After you wrote your service, use it inside any component you wish.

```
export class Tab1Page {

@ViewChild("barCanvas", { static: true }) barCanvas: ElementRef;
private barChart: Chart;

constructor(private mqttService:MqttService){}

ngOnInit() {
    this.barChart = new Chart(this.barCanvas.nativeElement)//no idea how to init this Class,
  this.mqttService.onTopic("app/chart").subscribe(data=>{
     this.refreshChart(this.barChart,data)
   })
}

 refreshChart(chart:Chart,data){
 //refresh the chart
 }

}
```

Comment: Cheers, this seems fairly understandable. Only question is what `header` you're referencing within the `onTopic()` method?

Comment: I assumed that the client library has a feature that sending header params.but ofcourse you don't have to.I forgot the put it as function param.I edited the method.

Comment: Yeah my bad, just getting caught up on the irrelevant details.